# Redis client supported by AWS-SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, redis, amazon-elasticache

Does AWS have any built-in Redis clients or must I use a Lambda Layer?

I have an existing AWS Lambda function accessing an existing AWS Redis cache. It all works great except that it requires me to have a Lambda Layer to include my Redis client (currently async-redis). I'd like to remove the Lambda Layer if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not that I know of. You can package a Redis client SDK with your Lambda function or supply the same thing in a Lambda Layer.

AWS generally does not create client data SDKs for third-party software products such as databases. It provides SDKs to manage the AWS resources (the infrastructure) associated with the corresponding managed AWS service e.g. ElastiCache for Redis, OpenSearch, and DocumentDB but not the underlying data API.